# how to check if List<string> exists all values in other List<string>

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to figure out how to check if all values match other List values.

Example:

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>() {"banana","apple","coconut"}
List<string> bar = new List<string>() {"banana","apple","coconut","mango", "lemon"}
```

if every foo list item exists in bar then return true and if at least one is not in foo list then return false.
AND if
Example:

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>() {"banana",}
List<string> bar = new List<string>() {"banana","apple","coconut","mango", "lemon"}
```

should return true

AND if
Example:

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>() {"banana","melon"}
List<string> bar = new List<string>() {"banana","apple","coconut","mango", "lemon"}
```

should return false

AND if
Example:

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>() {"banana","apple","coconut","mango", "lemon"}
List<string> bar = new List<string>() {"banana"}
```

should return false

sory for all the changes. got to do this fast :D

Comment: Welcome. Those are different requirements, I don't think there's a clean way to have an all-in-one solution. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you thought about duplicates? eg. `foo` containing `apple` twice but `bar` only has 1 instance of `apple`?

Comment: "and if at least one is not in foo" did you mean "and if at least one is not in ___bar___"

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think you can use something like

```
 var resultBool = foo.All(x => bar.Any(y => x == y));
```

Here, we are comparing the lists by each value. if the foo has a string value which not present in the bar then the result will be false.

I think this will help you to find a solution.

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>() { "banana", "apple", "coconut" };
List<string> bar = new List<string>() { "banana", "apple", "coconut", "mango", "lemon" };
//true
var test1 = foo.All(x => bar.Any(y => x == y));

List<string> foo2 = new List<string>() { "banana", };
List<string> bar2 = new List<string>() { "banana", "apple", "coconut", "mango", "lemon" };
//true
var test2 = foo2.All(x => bar2.Any(y => x == y));

List<string> foo3 = new List<string>() { "banana", "melon" };
List<string> bar3 = new List<string>() { "banana", "apple", "coconut", "mango", "lemon" };
//false
var test3 = foo3.All(x => bar3.Any(y => x == y));

List<string> foo4 = new List<string>() { "banana", "apple", "coconut", "mango", "lemon" };
List<string> bar4 = new List<string>() { "banana" };
//false
var test4 = foo4.All(x => bar4.Any(y => x == y));
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually fairly straight forward using `Intersect()`

```
foo.Intersect(bar).Count() == foo.Count()
```

Comment: yeah. it works for first two, but not quite what i'm looking.

Comment: Given the updated requirements this should still be okay

Comment: Why is it not what you are looking for. Could you explain? How can we answer if we don't have all the information.

Comment: Updated the example with randomizing the list, still seems good to me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AyINza

Comment: I guess this will fail if the same item repeats in foo list

Comment: Thanks this actually works. @krishnaMuppalla foo and bar strings will never have repeat items.

Comment: If it works for you, then please consider upvoting and accepting this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with `Except`

```
var matching = !foo.Except(bar).ToList().Any();
```

Comment: What if the items are out of order?

Comment: Yes, fails on randomizing the order - https://dotnetfiddle.net/f6tres (You may have to run it multiple times, for Test1RandomOrder to print false instead of true)

Comment: Yep works now with randomized list - https://dotnetfiddle.net/jBL1sd